# Sending redux function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm very new to redux and I've created a basic rock paper scissors app.  However I am not sure how to pass in a function.  The user interface is below:

```
let App = ({humanScore,computerScore,userWinsGame,computerWinsGame}) => {

return (
    <div>
       Human:{humanScore}
       Computer: {computerScore}
    <br/>
    <button value='Rock' onClick={(e) => userChoice(e.target.value)} >Rock</button>
    <button value='Paper' onClick={(e) => userChoice(e.target.value)} >Paper</button>
    <button value='Scissors' onClick={(e) => userChoice(e.target.value)} >Scissors</button>
    <button onClick={() => userWinsGame()} >UserWins</button>
    <button onClick={() => computerWinsGame()} >ComputerWins</button>
    </div>
 );
};
```

The userChoice function looks like this:

```
let userChoice = (userInput) => {
    var computerInput = computerChoice();
    console.log("TEST" + userInput);
    if (
        (userInput == 'Rock' && computerInput == 'Scissors')||
        (userInput == 'Paper' && computerInput == 'Rock') ||
        (userInput == 'Scissors' && computerInput == 'Paper')
    ) {
         {comWins};
         console.log('User chose ' + userInput + 'Computer chose ' + computerInput);
    } else {
         console.log('User chose ' + userInput + 'Computer chose ' + computerInput);
    }
  }
```

And the app container is like this:

```
let AppContainer = connect(
state => ({
    humanScore: state.getIn(['data', 'users','human']),
    computerScore: state.getIn(['data', 'users','computer'])
}),
dispatch => ({
    comWins: () => dispatch(computerWins()),
    userWinsGame: () => dispatch(userWins()),
    computerWinsGame: () => dispatch(computerWins())
})
)(App);
```

However I keep getting the message 'comWins' is not defined  no-undef.  Sorry for the poor description, but any help would be much appreciated!

The reducer is below:

```
  const initialState = fromJS({
  users: {
    human: 0,
    computer: 0
  }
});


const dataReducer = handleActions({
    [actionTypes.USER_WINS]: (state) =>
        state.setIn(['users','human'], 
 state.getIn(['users','human'])+1),
    [actionTypes.COMPUTER_WINS]: (state) =>
        state.setIn(['users','computer'],state.getIn(['users','computer'])+1),
},
initialState);
```

My action file is this:

```
 const actionTypes = mirrorKeyValue([
'USER_WINS',
'COMPUTER_WINS'
```

]);

```
const {
userWins,
computerWins,
} = createActions({
[actionTypes.USER_WINS]: () => ({}),
[actionTypes.COMPUTER_WINS]: () => ({})

});


export {actionTypes,
   userWins,
   computerWins}
```

Comment: Do you have a reducer? Can you show it to us? It should be the reducer who has the logic to determine who wins the game and update the state accordingly. Also `{comWins}` seems to be a weird expression and that's where you are getting undefined.

Comment: I've added it now!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `comWins` in  App

```
let App = ({humanScore,computerScore,userWinsGame,computerWinsGame}) => {
```

But trying to use `{comWins};`

This is why it is giving `not defined error`

Also you can call it as `{props.comWins()}` without passing in App.

Comment: That fixed the undefined error (thank you!) but I'm not clear how to actually invoke the comWins functions when the computer wins!  Thanks

Comment: You are dispatching computerWins() function when computer wins.It should be present in your action file.Can you post that also?

Comment: still having an issue?

Comment: Yep, it still doesn't work- I just don't know where to put the comsWins function after the user has inputted a choice!

Comment: Updated some login in new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let App = ({humanScore,computerScore,userWinsGame,computerWinsGame}) => {

return (
    <div>
     //You are directly getting score here
       Human:{humanScore}
       Computer: {computerScore}
    <br/>
    <button value='Rock' onClick={(e) => userChoice(e.target.value)} >Rock</button>
    <button value='Paper' onClick={(e) => userChoice(e.target.value)} >Paper</button>
    <button value='Scissors' onClick={(e) => userChoice(e.target.value)} >Scissors</button>
    //no need to call extra functions
    </div>
 );
};


let userChoice = (userInput) => {
    var computerInput = computerChoice();
    console.log("TEST" + userInput);
    if (
        (userInput == 'Rock' && computerInput == 'Scissors')||
        (userInput == 'Paper' && computerInput == 'Rock') ||
        (userInput == 'Scissors' && computerInput == 'Paper')
    ) {
      //calling user winning function here
         {userWinsGame()};
         console.log('User chose ' + userInput + 'Computer chose ' + computerInput);
    } else { 
      //calling computer wining function
computerWinsGame()

         console.log('User chose ' + userInput + 'Computer chose ' + computerInput);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm now getting userWinsGame is undefined!